# Python Turtle window only pops up for a second

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making my first few games in python, and I've chosen Snake and Egg Catcher as my projects. My issue is that when I execute my code the graphics window only pops up for a second. I'm assuming that when my code reaches the end it automatically closes the window, but I want this window to remain for my game.

What can I add to make sure that my graphics window persists so that I can play the game?

Many thanks!

```
import random
import turtle as t


    #Creating the snake

caterpillar = t.Turtle()
caterpillar.shape('square')
caterpillar.color('red')
caterpillar.speed(0)
caterpillar.penup()
caterpillar.hideturtle()


# Creating the powerup

leaf = t.Turtle()
leaf_shape = ((0,0), (14,2), (18,6), (20,20), (6,18), (2,14))
t.register_shape('leaf', leaf_shape)
leaf.shape('leaf')
leaf.color('green')
leaf.penup()
leaf.hideturtle()
leaf.speed(0)


# Settling our score

game_started = False
text_turtle = t.Turtle()
text_turtle.write('Press SPACE to start', align = 'center', font ('Arial',16,'bold'))
text_turtle.hideturtle()

score_turtle - t.Turtle()
score_turtle.hideturtle()
score_turtle.speed(0)

# Game functions

def outside_window():
    pass
def game_over():
    pass
def display_score(current_score):
    pass
def place_leaf():
    pass
def start_game():

    global game_started

    if game_started:

        return

    game_started = true

    score = 0   
    text_turtle.clear()

    caterpillar_speed = 2
    caterpillar_length = 3
    caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
    caterpillar.showturtle()
    display_score(score)
    place_leaf()

# Game Drivers

while True:

    caterpillar.forward(caterpillar_speed)

    if caterpillar.distance(leaf) < 20:

        place_leaf()
        caterpillar_length = caterpillar_length + 1
        caterpillar_speed = caterpillar_speed + 1
        score = score + 10
        display_score(score)

    if outside_window():
        game_over()
        break

t.onkey(start_game, 'space')
t.listen()
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is that turtle or pygame?

Comment: This is a turtle - apologies if this was mistagging!

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code doesn't even get to the point of opening a graphics window due to syntax errors:

```
score_turtle - t.Turtle()
text_turtle.write('Press SPACE to start', align = 'center', font ('Arial',16,'bold'))
```

Should be:

```
score_turtle = t.Turtle()
text_turtle.write('Press SPACE to start', align='center', font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
```

In addition:

- You have lots of errors with respect to *global* variables -- I
  suggest you (re)read about how globals are handled in Python.
- Your `while True:` loop keeps your game from starting correctly and
  doesn't have any place in an event-driven program.
- Your caterpillar starts atop your leaf so your game over
  scenario triggers immediately.

I've reworked your code below just enough to get the game started cleanly, you still have lots of work to do:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# Game functions

def outside_window():
    return False  # implement this for real

def game_over():
    pass  # implement this for real

def display_score(current_score):
    pass  # implement this for real

def place_leaf():
    leaf.hideturtle()
    leaf.goto(100, 100)  # implement this for real
    leaf.showturtle()

def start_game():
    global score
    global caterpillar_speed
    global caterpillar_length

    screen.onkey(None, 'space')

    score = 0
    text_turtle.clear()

    caterpillar_speed = 2
    caterpillar_length = 3
    caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
    caterpillar.showturtle()

    display_score(score)
    place_leaf()
    crawl()

# Game Drivers

def crawl():
    global score
    global caterpillar_speed
    global caterpillar_length

    caterpillar.forward(caterpillar_speed)

    if caterpillar.distance(leaf) < 20:

        place_leaf()

        caterpillar_speed = caterpillar_speed + 1
        caterpillar_length = caterpillar_length + 1
        caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)

        score = score + 10
        display_score(score)

    if outside_window():
        game_over()
    else:
        screen.ontimer(crawl, 100)

screen = Screen()

# Creating the powerup

leaf_shape = ((0, 0), (14, 2), (18, 6), (20, 20), (6, 18), (2, 14))
screen.register_shape('leaf', leaf_shape)

leaf = Turtle('leaf', visible=False)
leaf.color('green')
leaf.speed('fastest')
leaf.penup()

# Creating the caterpillar

caterpillar = Turtle('square', visible=False)
caterpillar.color('red')
caterpillar.speed('fastest')
caterpillar.penup()

# Settling our score

text_turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
text_turtle.write('Press SPACE to start', align='center', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))

score_turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

screen.onkey(start_game, 'space')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```